# PHP: Find absolute URL of project root

Tags: php, apache

I have a PHP project that is supposed to be installed on different servers.
It has an include file named `includes.php` in the project root directory that can be called from several locations throughout the project, let's say from files `file1.php` (in the same location as `includes.php`), `subdir/file2.php`and `subdir2/file3.php`. The includes file contains a function that is supposed to return the absolute URL of my entire project, for example `http://www.myserver.com/myproject/`, no matter from which file the function was called.

- I cannot use `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` because that returns the URL of the file calling the function (which varies). I don't want to pass a parameter that says "go up two directories" or something like that because there is a huge number of places this URL-function can be called from.
- I cannot use `__FILE__` and `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` (which is recommended by some) because our server has some strange configuration such that `__FILE__` is not in a subdirectory of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`. (I am writing the project for my school but it is supposed to be distributed to other schools.)

My last solution was to take `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`, remove the file part and to use `get_headers()` to check if a known file (`dummy.php`) can be found in this directory. If not, I check the parent directory and so on. Unfortunately, `get_headers()` doesn't return anything in our school server (it works on my test system at home, though).

One solution that works (but that I don't really like) is to have the project root URL in a config file.

Does anyone have another idea for that? Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
OK, I found a solution on my own that works for me. I am still open to comments how to do it better, maybe without using `debug_backtrace()`? Is there a reason not to use this function?

```
function urlPath()
{
    $trace = debug_backtrace();
    $first_frame = $trace[count($trace)-1]; 
    // the lowest frame gives us the filename from which the first call was made

    $callerdir = dirname($first_frame['file']);
    $includedir = dirname(__FILE__);
    $rootLength = strlen($includedir);
    $subDir = substr($callerdir, $rootLength);
    $subdirDepth = substr_count($subDir,DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    // I use the fact that the include file is in the project root folder, so its 
    // folder path must be a prefix of any other file's folder path. I remove this 
    // prefix and count the number of path separators to get the "relative depth".

    $pageURL = 'http';
    if (isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) && $_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") 
    {
        $pageURL .= "s";
    }
    $pageURL .= "://" . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
    if (isset($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]) && $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") 
    {
        $pageURL .= ":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"];
    } 
    $pageURL .= $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    // I get the absolute URL of the calling page

    for ($i = 0; $i <= $subdirDepth; $i++)
    {
        $idx = strrpos($pageURL,'/');
        $pageURL = substr($pageURL, 0, $idx);
    }
    // I remove the required number of subdirectories plus one for the filename

    return $pageURL;
}
```

Comment: Does the file where this "return-the-project-root-url" function would be placed have a known relation to the project root? Or do you have  front controller (a file where every request get sent)?

Comment: Yes, the includes.php is in the project root directory. No, I don't have a front controller.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted something similar. However wanted the file name omitted.

I hope this helps mate!

**RAW Approach:**
This took me a while to perfect, and I kept as an example for people or projects where no variables are required. For your situation, you can make a global.

```
$current_url = (empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "http://" : "https://") . ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) . (((empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'http' : 'https') == "http" && $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 80 || (empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'http' : 'https') == "https" && $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "" : ":" . $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']) . (preg_replace("!^". preg_replace("!". $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] ."$!", "", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) ."!", "", __DIR__));
```

**OR, Simpler Approach :)**

```
$protocol = ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off') || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https://" : "http://";
$path = substr( dirname(__FILE__), strlen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']));
$current_url = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $path;
```

**Example Output:** (https, http, port, etc)

```
    https://example.xyz/base/path/without/file/
    http://another.example.com/uploads/test/
    http://www.return.url:81/blah/blahblah/example/
```